# Can multiple HotChocolate ObjectTypes of the same Type can be registered and used in different queries?

Tags: .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

We receive our data from the EF Core Model directly. Currently there is one registered `ObjectType` with configuration. Is it possible to register a second object type of the same Type with different configuration (properties to ignore, different property namings etc). Both should be used in different Query methods ? I tried but got an error that:  `The name 'X' was already registered by another type`.

Example:

```
ObjectType<Doc> - this is already created that maps to the EF Core model

ObjectType<DocSimplified> - I want to create a second one with subset of props to return and different namings

getDoc() query uses the first

getDocSimplified() - this second query that I wish to return the second simplified objecttype
```